# how to add label text from data table

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i my aspx page i have number of lables for that i need assign text from data table.
label id like label1,lable2....

datatable

```
val// column name and row values

1. name  
2. age   
3. ph
4. address etc..

 aspx page // design 

 <table width=100% >
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 643px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr></table>
```

i tried below code

```
string label_te = null;
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in obj_dt.Rows)
   {
       i++;
       label_te = dr.Field<string>("val");

       Label+i.Text = label_te.ToString();
   }
```

i know above code is error.any idea to get it

Comment: You cannot do - `Label+i.Text`. What is your ASPX page look like?

Comment: I don't understand, what you want to achieve? Why don't you bind it with Grid? Or please elaborate the requirement...

Comment: <table width=100% >
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 643px">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr></table>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
   string label_te = null;
   int i = 0;
   foreach (DataRow dr in obj_dt.Rows)
   {
       i++;
       label_te = dr.Field<string>("val");
       Label l = this.FindControl("Label"+i.ToString()) as Label;
       if(l!=null)
       {
         l.Text = label_te.ToString();
       }
   }
```

Comment: its showing null reference exception " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Happy please see my edit. How many rows does your `DataTable` have, and do you have the same number of labels on your form?

Comment: **this.FindControl** won't work if **Label** controls are nested inside other controls. You need to find them recursively like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16562322/find-a-control-in-current-page/16570702#16570702)

Comment: The table is not runat server

Comment: @Happy is the table in your example nested inside any other server controls? I tested and this works for me

Answer (score 1):

`Label+i.Text` is not a valid code.

Instead, you want to create **Label** controls dynamically, and add those to **PlaceHolder** (or Panel) control.

### ASPX

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
```

### Code Behind

```
string label_te;
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in obj_dt.Rows)
{
    i++;
    label_te = dr.Field<string>("val");
    var label = new Label
    {
        Text = label_te, 
        ID = "Label" + i
    };
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(label);
}
```

### Update:

According to your last updates, you are just trying to short-cut to assign value to Label. **It is not a proper way of doing that; it is really fragile.** Instead, you want to name those **Label** properly like `FirstName`, `LastName` and assign them.

```
string label_te;
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in obj_dt.Rows)
{
    i++;
    label_te = dr.Field<string>("val");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label_te))
    {
        ValLabel.Text = label_te;
    }

    i++;
    label_te = dr.Field<string>("AnotherField");
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(label_te))
    {
        AnotherFieldLabel.Text = label_te;
    }
}
```

Or use **GridView**, **ListView** or **Repeater** control like Hitesh suggested.

Comment: i already having tables with drop down list.i need insert into table

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using GridView, [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) for GridView example